# Why doesn't Smaug die in the 2nd Hobbit film if it was titled the 'Desolation of Smaug'?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, smaug, desolation-of-smaug, title-explanation

Doesn't desolation mean *a state of complete emptiness or **destruction***?

So ***why doesn't Smaug perish by the end of the 2nd Hobbit film if the film's title was made to describe his end?*** He only dies at the start of the 3rd film: Battle of Five Armies. Does Jackson say why?

Comment: This question seems to be asking why the movie was titled Desolation of Smaug, while the linked one is asking why he didn't die from a narrative point of view.

Comment: @ibid That is most definitely not what they're asking. They're asking why Smaug wasn't killed in the second film considering it's title. That's what they wrote in the title, and in the body.

Comment: @Edlothiad - the answers in the linked question only explain why he wasn't killed considering the narrative, not considering the title.

Comment: @ibid *Does Jackson say why?* Yes he does, he says **And so it was a deliberate choice to end the second movie on a cliffhanger.** So the although the title calls for his destruction, he wasn't killed because Jackson wanted a cliffhanger. Answered

Comment: @Edlothiad that is only true _if you interpret "desolation" to mean "destruction" in the fist place_.

Comment: To summarise [what I've said in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/conversation/desolation-of-smaug) here, the dupe target is a question of narrative timing, why not end the 2nd film with Smaug's death but instead start the 3rd with it, while this question asks "the title says _desolation_, I see none", which is answered below by considering different meanings of the word _and_ by quoting from the book to show which one is most likely correct.

Comment: Scrolling under "Community" shows me [this](https://gyazo.com/cc09269a8a97f0d690f1eae07cbbccfc). I voted to close because the linked answer already answered this question, and it seems that the OP subsequently closed it by themselves.

Comment: @SQB If OP thinks their question is a dupe, then IMO none of our arguments are relevant anymore.

Comment: @KutuluMike: I disagree. This is clearly a completely different question than the so-called duplicate, with a completely different answer, and if the OP thinks otherwise, then either the OP is simply wrong, or the OP needs to learn to express his/her thoughts better.

Comment: @Martha did you just say the OP is wrong?! How can you say the OP is wrong..? It is literally their question

Comment: @Edlothiad - New user, may have misunderstood the meaning/purpose of the duplicate prompt. I can definitely see it happening.

Comment: Either way, the question of what "desolation" here means is a good question and if OP really didn't mean it, then someone else should post it as a new question and have a mod merge these two answers over there.

Comment: It's a subjective genitive, not an objective.

Comment: Who even opened this again? I marked it as a duplicate already...

Comment: @Lampham: did you even bother reading any of the comments? This is a totally different question than the timeline one: it's asking about the meaning of the title, not the narrative choices.

Comment: Excuse me, but I believe I'm the one asking the question here, and I'm completely satisfied with the answer provided in the linked dupe, so I closed this.To make stuff clear, my question has been edited

Comment: @Lampham your edit has been rejected as it is harmful to the post. Unfortunately, the post received a wealth of upvotes regardless of the low quality nature of the original post. The post also would not have been deleted as Very Low Quality as it had indeed answered the (**wrongly intrerpreted**) question. The only action you can take is to accept the other answer, or leave them both unaccepted.

Comment: truly amazing a 2 sentence answer with no quotes garners 96 upvotes, while I got over 8 downvotes to my question.. amazing how you dont get 96 votes as well for [your well-researched post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159579/how-large-was-khazad-dûm/159589#159589) here @Edlothiad. Id accept SQBs answer but the 2 sentence post owner would be getting the populist badge for that...

Comment: Please don't make edits which **invalidate existing answers** to your question.

Answer (score 113):

It means "the desolation *caused by* Smaug".

In the book, this is the description given to the barren area around the Mountain, specifically to the south and west. (The map displays north to the left.)

[image: Thror's map from The Hobbit]

> In two days going they rowed right up the Long Lake and passed out into the River Running, and now they could all see the Lonely Mountain towering grim and tall before them. The stream was strong and their going slow. At the end of the third day, some miles up the river, they drew in to the left or western bank and disembarked.  ... The next day they set out again. ... The land about them grew bleak and barren, though once, as Thorin told them, it had been green and fair. There was little grass, and before long there was neither bush nor tree, and only broken and blackened stumps to speak of ones long vanished. They were come to the Desolation of the Dragon, and they were come at the waning of the year.
>
> *The Hobbit*, Chapter 11, "On the Doorstep"

Comment: In the film Balin declares the ruins of Dale to be "the desolation of Smaug" as well.

Comment: Please don't make further edits until this Meta discussion has been resolved; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11022/was-i-right-to-roll-this-edit-back

Comment: In accordance with the consensus on the now 3-day-old [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11022/31394) (four answers with scores ranging from 6 to 9, all saying MG's edits should be left in place), **I've rolled back this post to the last edit made by Matt Gutting**. Please direct any further discussion about this to the meta post linked by @Valorum.

Comment: I've downvoted. This post was originally very poor quality and low value.

Answer (score 52):

*The Desolation of Smaug* does not mean *the Destruction of Smaug*.

## Dictionary Definition

> #### Definition of desolation
>
> 1. **the action of [desolating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desolate#h2)**
>
>    > the pitiful *desolation* and slaughter of World War I — D. F. Fleming
> 2. 1. **grief, sadness**
>
>       > ... he put his trembling hands to his head, and gave a wild ringing scream, the cry of *desolation*. — George Eliot
>    2. **loneliness**
> 3. **devastation, ruin**
>
>    > a scene of utter *desolation*
> 4. **barren wasteland**
>
>    > looked out across the *desolation*
>
> *desolation — [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desolation)*

So while I see how you thought *The Desolation of Smaug* meant Smaug being laid to waste, a more likely explanation is using the fourth meaning as given above: the barren wasteland around Smaug's lair in the mountain Erebor.

Of course, one of the other meanings could apply as well: the sadness or loneliness of Smaug or the grief or devastation caused by Smaug.

## *The Hobbit*

Now let's turn to the book.

[image: A map showing the Desolation of Smaug]

> The land about them grew bleak and barren, though once, as Thorin told them, it had been green and fair. There was little grass, and before long there was neither bush nor tree, and only broken and blackened stumps to speak of ones long vanished. They were come to the *Desolation of the Dragon*, and they were come at the waning of the year.
>
> *The Hobbit*, "On the Doorstep"

This quote, along with the map, clearly shows that it's indeed the fourth meaning that's used here, the barren wasteland around Erebor, which is what the party had just reached in the quote.

## Conclusion

Of course, as is the beauty of any language in which words can have several, related meanings, all these meanings are invoked when used in the film's title like this.

But it is clear that it does not mean Smaug being laid to waste.

Comment: “The Desolation of Smaug could be taken to mean the destruction of Smaug” — Not really, no. This doesn’t seem to be a valid usage of the word “desolate”, neither common nor uncommon. While “to desolate somebody” exists, its meaning is “to make (someone) feel utterly wretched and unhappy.”, not “to kill somebody”. And I don’t recall Bard bullying Smaug into unhappiness.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, that seems to be more or less the interpretation the querant assumed when asking this question.

Comment: @SQB Right, so the answer is *that's not what that word (ever) means*, not *the word might also mean something else*.

Comment: ....so while overall this is a great answer, I can't quite bring myself to upvote it, since you're encouraging OP to keep this (incorrect) definition in their mind (in addition to the multiple correct ones presented).

Comment: Given the "bruised and blackened stumps" where "before [the land] had been green and fair", I'll nitpick and say we have the third meaning, not the fourth. But that's a nitpick.

Comment: It's somewhat better, and I'll upvote, but I still think the key point is that OP is inventing a meaning for this phrase that it simply does not have in standard English. My guess is that the idea that "desolation" meant that Smaug would be killed, or even "desolated" (emotionally or otherwise), probably didn't occur to Tolkien or Jackson.

Comment: @KyleStrand to be honest, English is not my first language, so I'm absolutely open to suggestions.

Comment: I would just strengthen your statement--instead of saying that "desolation" here "could be taken to mean Smaug being laid to waste", I would say that the "laid to waste" definition can't really be applied to Smaug. (To be more specific, I don't believe that to "desolate" an individual being ever means "lay to waste"; even the meaning suggested by @KonradRudolph of emotional desolation is fairly rare as a verb.)

Comment: This answer could be vastly improved with freehand circles.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer (before MattGutting's edits to Daniel's answer). I'm very surprised that this answer wasn't given more upvotes.  It shows more research effort and less of a commentary post.